# Prevent multiple adds to listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

A user selects a pizza, size, etc. and the pizza is added to the basket (listview). The form clears but the user can click the add button again which adds unwanted rows to the listview. I've tried to implement a for loop to check if a check box is checked before a new record can be added. As a result, the wanted record adds to the listview but the message pops up x amount of times. This repetitive message box also occurs when the button is clicked with no checked boxes. Help please?

```
'Add Pizza to Listview
Private Sub btnAddPizza_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddPizza.Click
    Dim itemname As String
    Dim price As Decimal
    Dim qty As Integer
    grandtotal = 0
    'Add to list view
    For Each rb1 In {rb01, rb02, rb03, rb04, rb05, rb06, rb07, rb08, rb09, rb10, rb11, rb12, rb13, rb14, rb15}
        If rb1.Checked = True Then
            itemname = GetCheckedItem()
            price = CDec(pizzacost)
            qty = 1
            ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({itemname, qty, price}))
        ElseIf rb1.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("No pizza is selected", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End If
    Next
    'recalculate grandtotal (bottom of listview)
    For Each x As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        grandtotal += CDec(x.SubItems(2).Text)
    Next
    lblGrandTotal.Text = "£ " & grandtotal
    'Discard Pizza selection
    For Each rb In {rb01, rb02, rb03, rb04, rb05, rb06, rb07, rb08, rb09, rb10, rb11, rb12, rb13, rb14, rb15}
        rb.Checked = False
    Next
    For Each rb In {rbSmall, rbMedium, rbLarge, rbSuper}
        rb.Checked = False
    Next
    For Each rb In {rbDeep, rbThin, rbStuffed}
        rb.Checked = False
    Next
    lblTotalPizza.Text = ""
    itemname = ""
    price = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but I think your problem lies in the fact that you only want the code inside your for loop to execute once.  In other words, rather than this:

```
For Each rb In radioButtons
    If rb.Checked Then    ' This happens once per radio button
        ' Add item
    Else
        ' Show Error
    End If
Next
```

You want to do something like this:

```
Dim found As Boolean
For Each rb In radioButtons
    If rb.Checked Then    ' This happens once per radio button
        found = True
    End If
Next
If found Then    ' This happens once after the loop is done 
    ' Add item
Else
    ' Show Error
End If
```

However, LINQ makes something like that even easier, via it's `Any` extension method:

```
If radioButtons.Any(Function(rb) rb.Checked) Then
    ' Add item
Else
    ' Show Error
End If
```

Comment: Legendary stuff! Thank you

Comment: LINQ is the way to go. I personally would have `btnAddPizza.Enabled = radioButtons.Any(Function(rb) rb.Checked)` in the radiobutton click handler